# Display Custom Fields in related list

Tags: custom-field

[image]

In the related lists,Cluster Field Configaration,Currently iam showing only one field,can display other custom fields.thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can edit layout and go to related list section, add more fields. Search for articles.

Comment: edit,->related  list means ,i get childs,i dnt to display more childs,i want to display more field in the highted area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is how you can do this]

1. Go to Layout of your master object.
2. Scroll down to your related list and click on settings icon.
3. Now choose fields which you want to display in related list.

Refer to above snapshot. Hope I answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this guide [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_related_lists.htm&type=0)

1)Access the page layout editor.
2)Double-click a related list on the layout to edit it. ...
3)Select which fields to include in the related list, and define the order in which the fields display. ...
4)If desired, select other page layouts to apply your related list customizations to.